# How to check a String value with a name of specific data in Arraylist<String[][]>?

Tags: java, android

I have an `ArrrayList<String[][]>` with a couple of `String[][]` in it. I want to extract out the 2D array that have same name as my `String` value.

I have tried the method below and it end up with errors like:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

Code in my fragment:

```
//String value

String value = getArguments().getString("choices");

//2D arrays

String[][] volume = {
        {"(pascal)", "1"},
        {"(kilopascal)", "0.001"},
        {"(bar)", "0.00001"}}
String[][] length = {
        {"(Meter)", "1"},
        {"(Centimeter)", "100"},
        {"(Kilometer)", "0.001"}}
String[][] weight = {
        {"(kilometer per hour)", "1"},
        {"(mile per hour)", "0.6213711922"},
        {"(yard per hour)", "1093.6132983333"}}

//Array List

ArrayList<String[][]> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
stringList.add(weight);
stringList.add(length);
stringList.add(volume);

//Code for extracting the String[][] from arraylist

    ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < stringList.size(); i++) {
            if(stringList.get(i).toString().equals(value)){
                for (int y = 0; y < stringList.get(i).length;) {
                    data.add(stringList.get(i)[y][0]);
                    y++;
                }
            }
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, "onViewCreated: " + e );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really seems to be a scenario where you could use `HashMap<String, Double>`. It keeps the values in this form: `key (of type String) -> value (of type Double)`. So you could completely remove your whole `String[][]` complication.

Here is an example:

```java
String value = getArguments().getString("choices");

//HashMaps

HashMap<String, Double> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("(pascal)", 1d);
map.put("(kilopascal)", 0.001);
// and so on

// You should add everything here though and remove the need for an ArrayList. that just complicates things

map.get(value); // Returns the double value
```

I cannot understand exactly what you want to do and what is supposed to be in the `value` variable. When you need to differentiate the map types (volume, length etc..) add yet another map that as key has `String` and as value another `HashMap<String, Double>`.

P.S: Try to log everything when you don't understand what is happening, some of your `toString()` functions, return the reference of the object and not what you (most likely) expect.

Or even better, use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

By doing `stringList.get(i).toString()` you get the `String[][]` object cast `toString()`.
That only returns something like this `[[Ljava.lang.String;@762efe5d`.

So comparing this to the `value` is wrong. Look up what `stringList.get(i)[0][0]` and `stringList.get(i)[0][1]` is, to figure out yourself what to compare and what you need.

By what I'm given i don't know which value exactly you are looking for, but it should be pretty easy to figure that out yourself.

You can name `y` as `row` or `column` to make it more readable.

Also instead of String[][] you can maybe use a HashMap<String, String> to make things easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but I'm not looking to compare my String data to value in my String [ ][ ] , I just want to check if string data was **(weight)** it returns me the String[ ][ ] with name of **weight** so i can put it in another loop to extract the [i][0] from it.

Comment: @Daniel One technique i could think of is: Make the List a `HashMap<String, String[][]> stringList`, and then `stringList.add("weight", weight);` etc... This way you can choose the right string array based on its name. I do not think that there is an easy way to get the name of a variable.

And this way you can omit the first for loop and just say `String[][] chosen = stringList.get(value)`